# Delegate Methods not called in Class Instance

Tags: iphone, delegates, amazon-s3, subclass

I'm creating an instance of a class called S3ObjectController (S3OC) that has one method and four delegate methods. I create an instance of my S3OC, call an instance method from the S3OC Class (which I know fires from NSLog statements) but none of the associated delegate methods are called within the S3OC class. I have the delegate set to self in the method and the delegate declared properly in the .h header.

Thoughts? just to be clear, it's the (void)request methods in the .m file below I'm thinking should be called that aren't. I'm getting EXC BAD ACCESS errors. Is self getting released by ARC?

The entire .m file of the S3OC class is below:

```
#import "S3ObjectController.h"

@implementation S3ObjectController
@synthesize string;
@synthesize s3GOR, s3Client;

-(void)method
{
    NSLog(@"Method Called");
    s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
    s3GOR = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc]initWithKey:string withBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]];
    [s3GOR setDelegate:self];
    [s3Client getObject:s3GOR];
    NSLog(@"Method Finished");
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    NSLog(@"Response Key %@", response);
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"ObjectRequestKey = %@",request);
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Final Delegate Method");
}
```

Here's the header:"

```
@interface S3ObjectController : NSObject <AmazonServiceRequestDelegate>{
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSString *string;

    AmazonS3Client *s3Client;
    S3GetObjectRequest *s3GOR;
}

-(void)method;

@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, strong) S3GetObjectRequest *s3GOR;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AmazonS3Client *s3Client;

@end
```

Finally, here's how I call the method in another class:

```
for (NSString *name in nameArray){
        @try {
            S3ObjectController *localS3 = [[S3ObjectController alloc]init];
            localS3.string = name;
            [localS3 method];
            NSLog(@"called");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the header for this class?

Comment: I just edited the question with the header

Comment: The `AmazonServiceRequestDelegate` already declares those `did...` methods, so it is redundant to have the same method definitions in your header. Try to remove those and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Why are people downgrading my question? I don't understand.

Comment: @Eric - [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120155/author-asking-to-take-an-answer-down-so-it-looks-unanswered-why) might have something to do with it...

Comment: I could still really use the help on this question if people are willing to look past that thread.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you `@synthesize` the properties?  I suspect there is a conflict between the IVars you've defined and whatever you're using with `@property`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suspicions about ARC are true. Because delegate properties are usually weak references, they aren't enough to keep the object from being released.

Make an NSArray that's an iVar and add the S3ObjectController to it. If the delegates still don't fire, you know it's something else...

Edit:

so declare an NSMutableArray in the header of the class that contains your for loop, initialize it somewhere like this:

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

then use it like this:

```
for (NSString *name in nameArray){
@try {
        S3ObjectController *localS3 = [[S3ObjectController alloc]init];
        localS3.string = name;
        [localS3 method];
        [myArray addObject:localS3];
        NSLog(@"called");
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand more about what you mean with: Make an NSArray that's an iVar and add the S3ObjectController to it. If the delegates still don't fire, you know it's something else...
Maybe some placeholder code?

Comment: Hmmm, the delegate methods do fire now. What does that mean and how did you know to do that? By adding localS3 to the array it has to retain it? Can you explain more?

Comment: yea, so when you add an object to the NSMutableArray, it retains it, or in ARC terms, it has a strong reference. However, the delegate property of the object only has a weak reference, which is not enough to keep it alive in the ARC environment.

Comment: Is there a way to make the delegate property strong? I don't want to make localS3 a global variable. How would you suggest I get the delegate methods to fire?

Comment: Unless you have the source code for the S3ObjectController you can't. You'll have to come up with some way of keeping the pointer alive. What is wrong with making it global?